# jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0 .. I want submit won't reload the page when it's valid

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, validation

```
$("#da-ex-validate2").validate({
                rules: {
                    details: {
                        required: true,
                        rangelength: [1, 500]
                    },
                    editor1: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 1
                    },
                    title: {
                        required: true,
                        rangelength: [1, 100]
                    },
                    SlideDeckPhoto: {
                        required: "#iButton:checked",
                        accept: ['.jpeg', '.png', '.jpg', '.gif']
                    },
                    min1: {
                        required: true,
                        digits: true,
                        min: 5
                    },
                    max1: {
                        required: true,
                        digits: true,
                        max: 5
                    },                          
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
                    },
                    range1: {
                        required: true,
                        digits: true,
                        range: [5, 10]
                    }

                },
                invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                        var message = errors == 1
                        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
                        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
                        $("#da-ex-val2-error").html(message).show();
                    } else {
                        $("#da-ex-val2-error").hide(); // it's not work !!! and the page is reload !!
                    }
                }
            });
```

I would also would like to save my form values to MySql without reload the page .
Please help ! I read so many post and tried so many thing !
If you put a code please tell where to put it ..
BTW my form has few input fields and also an file input field .
PLEASE HELP !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, put it after invalidHandler :

```
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var dataString = $('#YourFormID').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'yourpage.php',
                    data: dataString,
                    success:  function() {
                        $('#YourErrorDivID').hide();
                        $('#YourSuccessDivID').html("Your Message").show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

return false from the submit handler

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can anyone please help ?

Comment: Your solution didn't work 'cause if I want to use it I also need the jQuery form plugin . Check my solution it is much simple !